# How to add margin or padding on pseudo element 'content' next to 'background-image'

Tags: css

I'm trying to to have an icon (=background image) and text next to a checkbox. I have added image and text via a before pseudo element 15px on the right of the check box, which is where the background image then appears. Unfortunately the text (= content) starts where the background image is so they are overlapping. I have tried to move the text a bit right by adding spaces in "content", but \0020 works only once.

Please see my below snippet.

Could anyone help how I can align the background image and text neatly next to each other?

Thank you very much in advance!!

David

```css
.subcategory1::before {
    content: "\0020 \0020 Cardio Entertainment";
    background-image: url(https://designmodo.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/designmodo-icon.png) !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-size: 15px;
    position: relative;
    left: 15px;
    white-space: nowrap; /* avoid line breaks in tool tip */

}
```

```html
<span class="subcategory1"></span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply adjust the padding and also background position if needed:

```css
.subcategory1::before {
  content: "Cardio Entertainment";
  background-image: url(https://designmodo.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/designmodo-icon.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat ;
  background-position:0 1px;
  padding-left: 18px;
  background-size: 15px;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<span class="subcategory1"></span>
```

Comment: Fantastic, 'background-position' in combination with 'paddin-left' allows to set properties separately and was the solution! Thank you so much Temani!